# clojure.core/for with Cypher ExecutionResult

Tags: clojure

```
(defn cypher
  [query]
  (let [result (-> *cypher* (.execute query))]
    (for [row result
          column (.entrySet row)]
      {(keyword (.getKey column))
       (Neo4jVertex. (.getValue column) *g*)})))

repl=> (cypher "start n=node:people('*:*') return n")
{:n #<Neo4jVertex v[1]>}
```

This query returns two results, yet I'm only able to ever see one using `clojure.core/for`. How should I be going about this?

The Neo4j docs have this example (which is what I'm trying to emulate):

```
for ( Map<String, Object> row : result )
{
    for ( Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet() )
    {
        rows += column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ";
    }
    rows += "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `clojure.core/doseq` ([docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq)) instead.

```
user=> (doseq [row [1 2 3]]
  #_=>        [result [4 5 6]]
  #_=>   (println (str {:row row :result result}))))
{:row 1, :result 4}
{:row 1, :result 5}
{:row 1, :result 6}
{:row 2, :result 4}
{:row 2, :result 5}
{:row 2, :result 6}
{:row 3, :result 4}
{:row 3, :result 5}
{:row 3, :result 6}
```

So, adapted to your example, something like the following might work:

```
; ...
(doseq [row result]
       [column (.entrySet row)]
  (println (str {(keyword (.getKey column)) (Neo4jVertex. (.getValue column) *g*)}))))
; ...
```

Note that `doseq` returns `nil`; you'll have to call something with side effects like  `println` in the body of the `doseq` form.

It looks like `clojure.core/for` does list comprehension, so something like the following actually returns a list:

```
user=> (for [row [1 2 3]
  #_=>       result [4 5 6]]
  #_=>   {:row row :result result})
({:row 1, :result 4} {:row 1, :result 5} {:row 1, :result 6} {:row 2, :result 4} {:row 2, :result 5} {:row 2, :result 6} {:row 3, :result 4} {:row 3, :result 5} {:row 3, :result 6})
```

Comment: Thanks. `for` does the same thing as `doseq` except it returns a sequence, which is what I need in this case rather than nil. `doseq` is more for side-effects like repeatedly calling .put

Comment: `(into [] (-> *cypher* (.execute query)))` in my example fixes it, but I'm not really sure why, since clearly it's iterable without `(into [] ...)`

Comment: Ah, I see, I must have misunderstood your actual question. I'm also trying to learn Clojure myself, and I was extremely confused by `for` versus `doseq` at one point recently.

Comment: So the problem is that whatever is returned by `(.execute query)` isn't iterable (at least with not in a way useful to `for`) without `(into [] ...)`?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that it can only be read once. But I'm not sure why it needs to be read more than once (is it?) in `for`.